# $(D^2 -1)y=0 \iff (D-\tanh x)(D+ \tanh x)y=0$ where $D \equiv \frac{d}{dx}$?!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV-xIhP7VU8) lecture, the professor explains that factoring differential operators if different from factoring numbers, and provides this example. I have no idea where it comes from and indeed why it is true. Could someone provide an explanation for the fact that:
$$(D^2 -1)y=0 \iff (D-\tanh x)(D+ \tanh x)y=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct. Multiplication of differential operators is composition, thus we have

$$\begin{align}
(D-\tanh x)(D+\tanh x) &= D^2 + \tanh' x + \tanh x \cdot D - \tanh x\cdot D - \tanh^2 x\\
&= D^2 + (1 - \tanh ^2 x) - \tanh^2 x\\
&= D + 1 - 2\tanh^2 x.
\end{align}$$

If we suspect the $\tanh$ is a typo, and it should have been $\tan$ instead, a similar computation yields

$$(D-\tan x)(D+\tan x) = D^2 +1.$$

The same would be obtained by the factorisation $D^2 + 1 = (D - i)(D+i)$.

Generally, we have

$$(D - f)(D + f) = D^2 + f' + f\cdot D - f\cdot D - f^2 = D^2 + f' - f^2.$$

And taking a second look, we had the wrong order of factors in the original, what we need is

$$\begin{align}
(D + \tanh x)(D - \tanh x) &= D^2 - \tanh' x - \tanh x\cdot D + \tanh x \cdot D - \tanh^2 x\\
&= D^2 - (\tanh' x + \tanh^2 x)\\
&= D^2 - (1 - \tanh^2 x + \tanh^2 x)\\
&= D^2 -1.
\end{align}$$

When apart from $D$ everything in the factors are constants, the factors commute, but when some non-constant function occurs, the product of differential operators is not commutative.

Comment: So what's the appropriate 'tan' factorisation for $D^2 -1$ ? Some sort of $\pm i\tan x$ ?

Comment: D'oh. Must have been blind. It's just the wrong order of factors. $(D+\tanh x)(D-\tanh x)$ produces $D^2-1$ as desired.